# How do I stub one method with different return values for different parameters in Mockito?

Tags: parameters, mockito, junit5, matcher, stubbing

I'm trying to stub the saveRecord(Record newRecord) method in databaseService to throw an exception if the newRecord has a value in the field1 attribute of "OldValue" and return a Record object if the value in the field1 attribute is "UpdatedValue".

```
public Record updateRecord(Record existingRecord) {
        try {
            if(existingRecord!= null) {
                existingRecord.setField1("UpdatedValue");
                Record newRecord = databaseService.saveRecord(existingRecord);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return newRecord;
    }
```

I've tried stubbing the method like so...

```
        Record existingRecord = new Record();
        existingRecord.setField1("OldValue");

        Record newRecord = new Record();
        newRecord.setField1("UpdatedValue");

        Exception exception = new Exception("Failed");

        doThrow(exception).when(databaseService).saveRecord(existingRecord);
        doReturn(newRecord).when(databaseService).saveRecord(newRecord);
```

I've also tried:

```
       doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Object argument = invocation.getArguments()[0];
            if (argument.equals(existingRecord)) {
                throw exception;
            } else if (argument.equals(newRecord)) {
                return newRecord;
            } 
            throw new InvalidUseOfMatchersException(
                String.format("Argument %s does not match", argument)
            );
        }).when(databaseService).saveRecord(any(Record.class));
```

No luck. Any ideas?

Comment: your last approach with `doAnswer()` should be the correct way. Could you debug it and check if you enter your expected conditionals? PS: Check if `.equals()` returns true when you expect them to be equal. Otherwise, you can cast the argument to your `Record` class and inspect your `field1`

Comment: Reveal the whole test class that also compiles.